# How can I split the values from one column into two using (preferably) a regex pattern?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have text file to load into a dataframe. the values, once loaded, are all in one column in the format:

`0 Alabama[edit]
1 Auburn (something somethign)
2 Florence (something somethign)
.
.
.
12 California[edit]
13 Angwin (something something)
14 Arcata (something something)`

I have to split the values into 2 columns: State and RegionName.

and State should be the index

all the state names have the [edit] suffix and the regions names have a (....) at the end.
before I'd clean the data I thought i can use the [edit] and (..) as a mask.

I tried to separate the two "values"

`df=pd.read_table("file.txt", names=["State","RegionName])
state=df[df["State"].str.contains(r"\[edit\]")]
region=df[df["State"].str.contains(r"\s+\(.*\)")]`

and tried to merge these somehow, with no luck and 
if i tried to use state and region to make a new df I'd get an index error

I tried to use .str.extract

`df.row.str.extract("(?P<State>\r\[\edit\]")`

but I got an error saying df has now .row(or.str) attribute and im sure the pattern is wrong aswell.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
df['state'] = np.where(df.place.str.contains('edit'), df.place, np.nan)
df['region'] = np.where(df.place.str.contains('\('), df.place, np.nan)
df.drop('place', 1, inplace =True)
df['state'].ffill(inplace = True)
df.set_index('state', inplace = True)

                    region
state   
Alabama[edit]       NaN
Alabama[edit]       Auburn (something somethign)
Alabama[edit]       Florence (something somethign)
California[edit]    NaN
California[edit]    Angwin (something something)
California[edit]    Arcata (something something)
```

Comment: thanks but i get an error saying dataframe object  has no .place attribute

Comment: Place is the column name. Replace it with the column name of your data frame

Comment: worked perfectly! I just had to switch the df["state"/"region"] order of execution and add a dropna() line. Thank you!